# How to redirect from component after action was called successfully in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a call to an API inside an action in redux.

```
export const registerUser = registeredUserData => async dispatch => {
  let messages;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/users/register', registeredUserData);
    messages = response.data
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      messages = error.response.data
    }
  }

  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_USER,
    messages,
  });
};
```

This action is called when a form is sumbitted.

```
const onRegisterUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    registerUser(registeredUserData);
  };
```

When, if a call was successfull I want to redirect to another page.
The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to implement `history.push()` in this case.

If I put it inside method of my component right after `registerUser(registeredUserData);` then it gets called right away no matter the response of the call. And I'm not sure if it is a good idea to redirect from the action itself.

All the help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example your action `registerUser` is a promise since it's an `async` function.  So you could rewrite your `onRegisterUser` to look like this:

```
const onRegisterUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    registerUser(registeredUserData)
        .then(() => /* success */)
        .catch(error => /* handle my failure */)
};
```

That being said you might want to consider creating `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` actions for your network call.  This allows you to potentially update the state of redux based on your register user api call.

You could modify your thunk to look like this:

```
export const registerUser = registeredUserData => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/users/register', registeredUserData);
    dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS,
      messages: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAILURE,
        messages: error.response.data,
      });
    }
  }
};
```

You can then use one of React lifecycle methods to check for the state in redux change.  Assuming the snippet is using react-redux and `connect`.

You might also want to consider looking into [action creators](https://redux.js.org/basics/actions#action-creators).

An alternative to using React lifecycle methods is to use something like [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) which can signal on the `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE` actions and do the history.push on your behalf.

You might also want to look at [react router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) if you haven't done so yet.  It provides ways to access history and manage routing.

The point of async / await is to not have to use a nested promise chain in the case of your example.

Your try / catch block is equivalent to your then / catch.  So if you want to use the above and have it catch when the response is a 400 you will either need to remove the try catch and handle the error in `onRegisterUser`, not recommended, or you will need to re-throw so that the `catch` is called when you call `registerUser`.

Here's an example on `registerUser` that should return a catch when failed response.

```
export const registerUser = registeredUserData => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/users/register', registeredUserData);
    await dispatch({
      type: REGISTER_USER,
      messages: response.data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      await dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER,
        messages: error.response.data,
        isError: true,
      });
      throw new Error(error.response.data);
    }
  }
};
```

You might want to replace `throw new Error(error.response.data)` with something more specific by decorating the error object.

Comment: tried to add then and catch to my function, but then works even when request return with 400 status

Comment: Right, that's because you are catching the failure case in your action.  Did you only apply the promise or did you also change your `registerUser` method?

You will have to double check the documentation for axios, I don't recall off the tope of my head, but it likely won't throw for a 400 response.  You will likely have to do a `if (!response.ok) { throw (my own error) }`

Comment: Yes, now it is working. I added ```throw``` in catch inside action

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. In your component, pass `this.props.history` as a parameter to the redux action. And from there, after the action is dispatched you can redirect to some other page.

**P.S: It's not a bad idea to redirect from the action itself.**

**Inside your component:**

```
const onRegisterUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    registerUser(registeredUserData, this.props.history);
  };
```

**Inside your action:**

```
export const registerUser = (registeredUserData, history) => async dispatch => {
  let messages;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/users/register', registeredUserData);
    messages = response.data
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      messages = error.response.data
    }
  }

  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_USER,
    messages,
  });

    history.push('/redirect-route);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Allan,**

You'll basically have `this.props.history.push` available from your `Router` which is passing it to all the `Route` components children in your app.

You can confirm this via `console.log('__props__', this.props)` in your `render` method for that component.

In order to implement this, I would suggest sending it as a callback to your action `registerUser`, in order to do this:

- **Add the `cb` to your action:**

```
export const registerUser = registeredUserData => async dispatch => {
  let messages;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post('/users/register', registeredUserData);
    messages = response.data
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      messages = error.response.data
    }
  }

  dispatch({
    type: REGISTER_USER,
    messages,
  });

  // maybe you want a conditional redirect?
  if(/*somecondition to check data or error?*/){
    cb && cb(); //if callback exists, invoke it
  }
};
```

- **And for: `onRegisterUser`:**

```
const onRegisterUser = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  registerUser(registeredUserData, () => {
    this.props.history.push(//route);
  });
};
```

Hope that works, if it doesn't please describe the behavior.

Comment: Why don't you handle OK inside try and KO inside catch?

Comment: Doesn't that make it utterly complicated for an action?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia, because he dispatches his action below, if we did it upthere we would lose the context.

Comment: Yep, question should be, why don't dispatch an action if success and another one if fails.

Comment: @RohitKashyap, this is actually the best way to do it, since he is using `async/await` pattern, if we have a `promise` returning from that action it would have been different.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia, neither you nor I know what kind of standards the user is following in his projects, this it totally up to him to decide what logic to use for dispatching OKs and KOs, I only implemented the necessary solution for his obstacle, without any main modifications for the logic he have with dispatching.

Comment: @SultanH. Agree with that, will be ok for this example but I don't agree with `the best way to do it`.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia, guide me through, what do you think the best approach for that would be?

Comment: I like the way he's using async/await here and try/catch. But for the way is handling response. As I see, is setting `messages` to be fulfilled with whatever response. Will be the same data if success or rejected?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia, from my perspective, he has this store that has the responses, whether in failure or success stored in `messages` attribute, I think, handling this type of content would be by checking whether an error data lives in it, or the data he actually wants, which would be adding complixity dealing with. I do share the same idea about this, I would have chosen to dispatch `REGISTER_DATA` / `REGISTER_ERROR` with different data allocation to the store.

Comment: @SultanH. What you're driving at is basically what wrote for the replacement for his `registerUser` action.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57125106/2211743

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia the fundamental issue with the action `registerUser` is that the try catch block doesn't do anything valuable to signal to the caller it failed in error.  Regardless if you use the promise route, the callback route, or the other answer to call history in action they should all be in the "try body" for success and catch for failure. In the case of this answer with node style callback:
`
try {
    if (cb) {
        cb(null, message);
} catch (error) {
    if (cb) {
        cb(error);
    }
}
`